# How do I import multiple values from views into multiple buttons in template?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a set of buttons in index.html and a dictionary with values for some buttons in views.py which I import via ajax. What I want to do is go through that dictionary and load each value into it's specific button.

This is basically the html.

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $(':button').on('click', function(event){
        $('#ID').val(this.id);          
        var tmp = this.id;
        $.ajax({
            type: $('#klik').attr("method"),
            url : $('#klik').attr("action"),
            data : $('#klik').serialize(),
            success: function(d){
                {% for gumb in buttons %}
                alert('alo')
                    $('#' + Gumb.id).val(d);
                {% endfor %}
                //$('#' + tmp).val(d); // this works only for one button, I tried using for loop for multple

            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Greska')
            }
        });       
    });
});
```

And as for views.py, this is what I'm returning.

```
def klik(request):
print('Test')
if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:
    print(request.POST)
    ID = request.POST['ID']
    vr = r[ID]
    gumbi = []
    g = Gumb(ID, vr)
    gumbi.append(g)
    ...something....
    d = dict()
    d['buttons']= gumbi
    #return render(request,'index.html', d)
    return HttpResponse(d)
```

There could be more Gumb in gumbi, and Gumb is a class where Gumb.id is the same ID as from the button in html and Gumb.b is the value I want in the button.

It works with only one button as tagged:

```
//$('#' + tmp).val(d);
```

if I return this in the views:

```
return HttpResponse(vr)
```

but not with multiple.

Comment: Hi, Idk about what framework you're using. But make sure you are returning a JSON Object

Comment: I'm Staring at `return HttpResponse(obj);`

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're returning a list of JSON object here.

```
[{d:data},{d:data}]

//ajax code
success: function(data) {
//use $.each here not the framework each
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        console.log(value) //iterates your data see dev tools console for prints
    })

}
```

Comment: My dictionary d from previous code at first looked like {'buttons': [(ID: r3s6, Value: 0)...]} and I have now rewritten it into e.g. {'r3s6': 0, ...}. I also tried to convert it into JSON in my html code like: `var myJSON = JSON.parse(d)` but I don't understand what index and value are in your code and how I could access my data in myJSON. Also, I tried putting some alerts in my success part of ajax to check if it worked, but no alerts popped up.

Comment: This d in  function(d) are all dictionary's keys sticked together... idk

Comment: I mean, does it even goes through your controller? as long as it can return an array of json objects like this `[{key:value},{key:value}]` we can work out the front end part

Comment: The problem is that when I try to convert my list or my dictionary into a json object, it becomes a big string (e.g. '{"r8s8": 0, "r8s7": 0, "r7s7": 1, "r7s8": 1}') and when I try to alert d[2], it returns 'r'. I don't know how to acces any data. I can't access it by keys, nor do I know which ones they are cz they vary.